# Google OAuth2: Programatically revoking a specific refresh token (but not access to app)

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

The application I'm working stores multiple refresh tokens for a given (Google Account, App) pair.
When deleting a refresh token from our database, we'd like to invalidate this token, but not any other currently valid refresh token issued for the same (Google Account, App).
Using 
    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
seems to invalidate all refresh tokens for (Google Account, App).
Question: is there a way to invalidate a single refresh token?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am guessing that currently there is no way.